# How to run `docker exec` with ssh command

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, docker

Not a fun one -

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ssh -i 'my.pem' "ubuntu@${addr}" "docker exec -ti '$name' bash"
```

I get this lame error:

```
the input device is not a TTY
```

with no context at all. docker runs fine on the machine. Anyone know what I can do to make this work as desired?

I also tried this, and I get this same exact error:

```
 ssh -i 'my.pem' "ubuntu@${hb_ip_addr}" "bash -c 'docker exec -ti '$name' bash'"
```

terrible.

Answer (score 1):

here is the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47025876/1223975

in short, you need:

```
ssh -tti
```

yes with two 't' args.

What a NIGHTMARE utility.

So this now works with `zsh` and `bashv5` on my macos machine:

```
 ssh -tti 'my.pem' "ubuntu@${addr}" "docker exec -ti $name bash"
```